# system validate not work using jQuery hidden form

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have in an index.php page two form, form1 contains input Required and a validate button which allows to hide form1 and display form2, and a form2 contains `<h1> i am in form2 </h1>`, i have applied validation system from jQuery, but it doesn't work.

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Makes "field" always required.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="form1">    
    <form id="myform">
       <label for="field">Required: </label>
       <input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
      <br/>
       <input type="submit" class="add-all" value="Validate!">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="form2">
    <h1>form2</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery code**

```
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({

  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true
    }
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form2").hide();

    $('.add-all').on('click', function(e) {
            $("#form1").hide();
            $("#form2").show();
    })
   })
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to show form 2 when form 1 is valid and submited?

Comment: @VanTho yes exactlly

Comment: I've posted my answer, you can check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this working snippet.

```js
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({

  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true
    }
  }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#form2").hide();
  $("#myform").submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
       // Hide form1 and show form 2 when form1 is valid
      $(this).hide();
      $("#form2").show();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Makes "field" always required.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="form1">
    <form id="myform">
      <label for="field">Required: </label>
      <input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
      <br />
      <input type="submit" class="add-all" value="Validate!">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="form2">
    <h1>form2</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I've removed your `click` event, replaced by `submit` event, because you need to hide/show form by `valid()` function, not just by `click` event.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

By placing the click event on the button, the function was being executed directly without wating for the validation check. I removed the click event from the button and called the function on success of the validation as per the docs, the right way to it is this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({

  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function() { 
  alert("Submitted!")
  var validator = $( "#myform" ).validate();
 console.log(validator);
  onsubmit();
  }
});

  $("#form2").hide();
  function onsubmit() {
    $("#form1").hide();
    $("#form2").show();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Makes "field" always required.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="form1">    
    <form id="myform">
       <label for="field">Required: </label>
       <input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
      <br/>
       <input type="submit" class="add-all" value="Validate!">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="form2">
    <h1>form2</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```